# MySQL output all records from table but add flag if value present in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to populate an autocomplete select field which needs to show all users but add a flag next to those that exist in the club table for the current club.

```
Users

user_id | first_name | last_name
--------------------------------
1       | Bob        | Smith
2       | Lisa       | Someone
3       | Bill       | Green
4       | Jane       | Hill


Club

club_id | user_id
-----------------
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 4
```

Output I need when I am looking for all users in the context of club "2"

```
1 | Bob  | Smith   | TRUE
2 | Lisa | Someone |
3 | Bill | Green   |
4 | Jane | Hill    | TRUE
```

I don't know why this is bending my mind so much...

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `left outer join`:

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name,
       (c.club_id = 2) as flag
from users u left join
     club c
     on u.user_id = c.user_id;
```

Note that the `flag` gets a value of `0` (false) or `1` (true).  If you want some other values for the flag, then you will need to use a `case` statement.

EDIT:

If you simply want the flag for each user, then the easiest way is:

```
select u.*,
       exists (select 1 from club c where u.user_id = c.user_id and c.club_id = 2) as flag
from users u;
```

Once again, this produces a 0/1 flag.  If you want a different value, then it needs to go into a `case`.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name,
       (c.user_id is not null) as flag
from users u left join
     club c
     on u.user_id = c.user_id and c.club_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks... this almost works however if a user is part of more than 1 club they appear in the output more than once... not ideal for my scenario.

Comment: Thanks for editing. it looks like its working... just needed an "As Flag" on the end of t. I'll mark as correct once I run a few more tests

Answer (score 0):

I originally misread your question, sorry. Here's what you're looking for:

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name,
       case when c.club_id is not null then true end as flag
from users u
left join club c on (u.user_id=c.user_id and c.club_id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Club c WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id) 
                THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE NULL 
        END FlagValue
FROM    users u
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/899594/2)

Comment: Thanks, close but this is returning TRUE if the user has ever been in any club, where as I need to scope to the current club context. I tried adding WHERE c.club_id = 1 but its still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

`select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
      , case when c.user_id is not null then 'TRUE' else '' end 
 from users u 
 left join club c 
     on u.user_id = c.user_id 
    and c.club_id = 2 
 order by u.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear about your problem statement, I created the tables and inserted the data -

```
create table users (user_id bigint not null, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100));
create table club (club_id bigint not null, user_id bigint not null);

insert into users values (1, 'Bob','Smith');
insert into users values (2, 'Lisa','Someone');
insert into users values (3, 'Bill','Green');
insert into users values (4, 'Jane','Hill');

insert into club values (1, 2);
insert into club values (2, 1);
insert into club values (2, 4);
```

And here is the query that I ran -

```
select users.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, 
case when club.club_id = 2 then 'TRUE' end as flag 
from users left join club on users.user_id = club.user_id;
```

And here's the output -

```
1   Bob Smith   TRUE
2   Lisa    Someone NULL
3   Bill    Green   NULL
4   Jane    Hill    TRUE
```